# cannot find the class file for com.android.volley.request

Tags: android, salesforce, android-volley

Hi i am trying to develop a android native App for salesforce by the help of

```
 Forcedroid Mobile SDK
```

my file or directory is as above figure
   [image]

But i am getting two error in my Mainctivity class

```
        private void sendRequest(String soql) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    RestRequest restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForQuery(getString(R.string.api_version), soql);

    client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) {
            try {
                listAdapter.clear();
                JSONArray records = result.asJSONObject().getJSONArray("records");
                for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                    listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                onError(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                           MainActivity.this.getString(SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().getSalesforceR().stringGenericError(), exception.toString()),
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

first error is

```
  api_version cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

and second error is

```
  The type com.android.volley.Request cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have little knowledge about android but SalesForce SDK is new for me.Not even single time i am able to run my created App "sfaDroidpp". Please take me out of this issue. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/native?

Comment: Yes.. I did same step and recheck my all step 4-5 times but still why i am getting this issue i am not able to understand so at last i post this question here.

Comment: It looks like maybe you didn't add Volley correctly to you project and build path.

Comment: @ItaiHanski.. I successfully resolve this issue but now i am getting another issue when i am running my android project it is showing some another UI while my UI is different . It is showing login & password by Sales-force company even my main.xml is diffrent.

Comment: @BlueGreen You should probably check the salesforce documentation for that.